# TNS_ADMIN / TNSNAMES location failover

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

Is there a way to have multiple `tnsnames.ora` locations defined? We currently use a server path like `TNS_ADMIN=\\192.168.1.100\infosys\oracle\tnsnames` but are in a situation this week where that server had to be taken offline for a couple days.

I've tried stacking locations similar to PATH variable but it doesn't work:

```
> set TNS_ADMIN=z:\Common\oracle;\\192.168.1.100\infosys\oracle\tnsnames
> mctnsping ora-server

McTnsping Utility by Michel Cadot: Version 2018.08.17 on 18-OCT-2018 11:16:33
Copyright (c) Michel Cadot, 2016-2018. All rights reserved.

*** TNS-03514: Failed to find tnsnames.ora file
```

Single location is fine:

```
> set TNS_ADMIN=Z:\Common\oracle
> mctnsping ora-server

Used parameter files:
Z:\Common\oracle\tnsnames.ora
...snip...    
Attempting to contact ora-server:1521
OK (201 msec)
```

How to have an alternate location without touching every client to change TNS_ADMIN?

Comment: If you look for a centralized alias resolution, then [Oracle Internet Directory](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/overview/index-082035.html) might be an option for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ echo "TNS1=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=o71.balazs.vm)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TNS1)))" > ~/tnsnames1.ora
[oracle@o71 ~]$ echo "TNS1=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=o72.balazs.vm)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TNS2)))" > ~/tnsnames2.ora
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat tnsnames1.ora
TNS1=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=o71.balazs.vm)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TNS1)))
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat tnsnames2.ora
TNS1=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=o72.balazs.vm)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TNS2)))
```

I changed the `HOST` and `SERVICE_NAME` values for demonstrating how name resolution still works after making one of the files inaccesible.

Now include them with `IFILE`:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ echo -e "IFILE=/home/oracle/tnsnames1.ora\nIFILE=/home/oracle/tnsnames2.ora" > ~/tnsnames.ora
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat ~/tnsnames.ora
IFILE=/home/oracle/tnsnames1.ora
IFILE=/home/oracle/tnsnames2.ora
[oracle@o71 ~]$ export TNS_ADMIN=/home/oracle
```

Test:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ tnsping tns1

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 18-OCT-2018 21:37:00

Copyright (c) 1997, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=o72.balazs.vm)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TNS2)))
OK (10 msec)
```

`tnsping` picked up the last occurence of the same TNS alias. Now make this second file inaccessible:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ mv /home/oracle/tnsnames2.ora /home/oracle/tnsnames2.ora.corrupt
```

Test again:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ tnsping tns1

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 18-OCT-2018 21:37:19

Copyright (c) 1997, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=o71.balazs.vm)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TNS1)))
OK (0 msec)
```

TNS resolution still works, but from the first file (`HOST`, `SERVICE_NAME`).

With this method you basically enumerate multiple files containing TNS aliases using the `IFILE` parameter, which was not designed for this, but it is something.

Comment: +1 for the information and education. However I can't use it here as it appears IFILE support is incomplete, at least on Windows. For our primary client app, ArcGIS Desktop, IFILE only works if the target .ora files are on the local client system. Network sources fail using both mapped drive and UNC paths. For mctnsping, using IFILE always fails.